# How to execute phantomjs file browser?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm new to phantomJs. I've installed phantomjs in my system(Ubuntu) and executed a sample code "test.js" in terminal like,

test.js:

> console.log("WELCOME TO PHANTOMJS");
>   phantom.exit();

In terminal

> phantomjs test.js

its executed fine shows expected output.

NOw my question is, Is there any possibilites to execute above js file in a browser by importing that js file in a html file like,

> <script src="test.js".....></script>

If is it possible means how to do?? Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short Version

You can't

### Detailed Version

In its current state, PhantomJS is a standalone process and needs to have the full control (in a synchronous matter) over everything: event loop, network stack, and JavaScript execution, ... yes you write scripts in Javascript but it's simply because it exposes a JavaScript API (also for coffee script).

"How to execute a nodejs module in browser?" It's pretty the same problem and you simply can't because of phantomjs/nodejs dependencies : what is `webpage` module in your favorite the browser ? But it's still possibe to share pure JS library.

So, you can't directly reference a phantomjs script in your browser, but you can communicate with a PhantomJS instance using HTTP GET/POST with [Web Server module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/). HEre is a topic on[Inter Process Communication](http://phantomjs.org/inter-process-communication.html) found on the Wiki.