# Is PhantomJS client side or server side?

Tags: phantomjs

Does PhantomJS work client side or server side? I know JavaScript can work client and server side, but I don't know which one PhantomJS is based on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute phantomjs file browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675031/how-to-execute-phantomjs-file-browser)

Answer (score 6):

> Is PhantomJS client side or server side?

**Is it client-side?**

- **Yes**, if you mean, does PhantomJS emulate/replace the browser which we usually think of as "client-side"--that is its purpose in life!
- **No**, if by "client-side", you mean "runs in a browser"--because PhantomJS itself **is** a browser (albeit with no visual display of the screen--hence the term "headless").

**Is it server-side?**

- **Yes**, if by "server-side" you mean PhantomJS could run on some computer which I might think of as a server, including one off in the cloud somewhere.
- **No**, if by "server-side" you mean PhantomJS implements, or would be used to implement, a web server handling HTTP calls and implementing some API.

Do you have some specific issue you were trying to solve, or is this just curiosity and clarification of terminology?

Comment: My purpose is when you run a code in PhantomJs is the ip that submits for that action the client's ip or the server's ip?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "client's IP or server's IP". The submitted IP will be that of the computer that is running PhantomJS.

Comment: Well, the computer running PhantomJS would be the server, not the client, since PhantomJS runs on the "backend"... so, the IP would be the server's ip...
I just saw the tool Apifier (https://www.apifier.com/): when you use it, it uses a pool of several IPs so maybe thats what you're looking for? (as you can see here : https://www.apifier.com/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is a headless browser. The PhantomJS API is used to control the browser itself, as well as allowing you to inject Javascript within the DOM context.

**PhantomJS is a HTTP client.**

You can put PhantomJS on a server to act as an automated client. In that way it you could consider it server side. But it is still a **HTTP client** at it's core.

The purpose of PhantomJS is instead of using a mouse and keyboard to control a browser and complete some actions, for instance: open a new window, type a url, enter, find a link and click it. You can automate those actions programmatically with Javascript.

If you are considering the conventional terminology meaning; code inside a loaded webpage being *Client Side* and code running on a HTTP Server being *Server Side*.
Usually PhantomJS is Client Side that is run on Server Side.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to say with your last paragraph. Can you expand that a bit?